# (SQL) How to aggregate "Total Quantity" values under one "Customer Name"

Tags: sql, aggregation

**So I have this simple query**

```
SELECT C.CustomerName, (P.Price * OD.Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, 
FROM Customers as C
INNER JOIN Orders AS O
ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
INNER JOIN OrderDetails AS OD
ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products AS P
ON OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
ORDER BY TotalQuantity DESC;
```

**This is the result**

```
CustomerName    TotalQuantity
Piccolo und mehr    13175
Simons bistro   13175
Mère Paillarde  12911.5
Queen Cozinha   10540
Split Rail Beer & Ale   5270
Ernst Handel    5270
Blondel père et fils    4332.650000000001
Frankenversand  3850
Ernst Handel    3850
Save-a-lot Markets  3512
Rattlesnake Canyon Grocery  3451
Suprêmes délices    3240
Old World Delicatessen  3094.75
Save-a-lot Markets  2970.96
Save-a-lot Markets  2880
```

As you can see "Save-a-lot Markets" are split into three records. What my code does is that it multiplies total product quantity by price for each individual order. What I need to do, is to aggregate all orders for each customer, so it would be ONE record for "Save-a-lot Markets" with a Total Quantity of 9,362.96.

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve that?

Sorry for a very sloppy explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want aggregation.  Note both the `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`:

```
SELECT C.CustomerName, SUM(P.Price * OD.Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, 
FROM Customers aC INNER JOIN
     Orders O
     ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID INNER JOIN 
     OrderDetails OD
     ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID INNER JOIN 
     Products AS P
     ON OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
GROUP BY C.CustomerName
ORDER BY TotalQuantity DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use aggregated function `sum` and `group by`

```
SELECT 
   C.CustomerName, 
   SUM(P.Price * OD.Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, 
FROM Customers as C
INNER JOIN Orders AS O
ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
INNER JOIN OrderDetails AS OD
ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products AS P
ON OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
GROUP BY 
    C.CustomerName
ORDER BY 
    TotalQuantity DESC;
```